# mysql get groups list with particular rights

Tags: mysql

I have three tables in mysql

groups, groups_rights, rights

structure is as follows

groups

```
id | name
----------
1  | Professionnel
2  | Surgerysync
```

rights

```
id | name
----------
11  | USERS-ACCESS
12  | PANEL-ACCESS
13  | MEMBER
```

groups_rights

```
id | group_id | right_id
--------------------
1  | 1        | 11
2  | 2        | 11
3  | 1        | 12
4  | 1        | 13
5  | 2        | 13
```

I want query to get the groups which don't have PANEL-ACCESS rights.

```
SELECT `groups`.`name`, `groups`.`id` FROM (`groups`) JOIN `groups_rights` ON `groups_rights`.`group_id` = `groups`.`id` JOIN `rights` ON `rights`.`id` = `groups_rights`.`right_id` WHERE `rights`.`id` NOT IN (11);
```

I am using above query but I am getting both group as result.

what is correct query to get only group that don't have PANEL-ACCESS.

Comment: Provide schema at http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1f0ce/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, your PANEL-ACCESS id is 12 so you should use `NOT IN (12)`

Secondly, instead of referring the rights.id which would be difficult many times, use rights.name.

Finally, get the list of groups which have PANEL-ACCESS and look for groups which are not present in that list. Here is the query that works for groups which don't have PANEL-ACCESS.

```
SELECT `groups`.`name`, `groups`.`id` FROM (`groups`)
where `groups`.`id` not in (
 SELECT `groups`.`id` FROM (`groups`)
 JOIN `groups_rights` ON `groups_rights`.`group_id` = `groups`.`id`
 JOIN `rights` ON `rights`.`id` = `groups_rights`.`right_id`
 WHERE `rights`.`name` = 'PANEL-ACCESS');
```